# AS3 instantiate an object without creating a class file

Tags: actionscript-3, class, instance

I have quite a basic question that has been bugging me for a while.

How do I  import a few movie clips from the library to the stage, they don't need any behavior just to be spawned dynamically.
Their behavior  may be set from the main class.

For example I want to create a few vector elements for a background and instantiate them randomly.

Thank you,
Yaniv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use new MovieClip() and than add it into stage or if you have a movie clip in your library you can give it a linkage name and than instantiate it with new

Comment: so I don't need a class file to give a linkage name, I'm a bit confused with these concepts.

Comment: if I do :  var bg:Bg1;  and then bg = new Bg1;  so what is the type of bg ? ( Bg1 is the linkage of a movie clip in the library)

Comment: It will be a MovieClip.

Comment: @Yaniv. If you dont associate a class with the MC in the library, flash pro will just create a class behind the scenes. So in your example, the auto-generated class is Bg1 - and it will be a subclass of MovieClip.

Answer (score 0):

Draw your stuff in Flash, then convert it to Symbol > MovieClip.

It the dialog panel, check "Export for Actionscript" and give it as Class Name the name you want for it , for example MyBackground. Let the base class flash.display.MovieClip.
Flash will prompt you with a warning "A Definition for the base class could not be found.....", and that's ok, it is just warning you that the class for it it's actually missing, and one will be autogenerated.

Later in your code you can instantiate it your class by simply:

```
  var back:MyBackground = new MyBackground();
```